# add array to a field in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have array : 
$ids=[123,234,567,8910,11324,1];

how to add this to one field in mysql.

After adding check if this id exists if it does not then add it to the same field.

I am looking at something like this.How do I do that .I really appreciate any help .Thanks in Advance.:

```
  --------------------- 
  | all_blocked_users |
  ---------------------
  |  123,234,567      |
  ---------------------
```

Comment: Don't go down this road.  Only madness and despair lie at the end.

Comment: This is, as @cHao suggested, a really poor design, and will only serve to make your life miserable.  Instead you should have a table of blocked users with a primary key.

Comment: @cHao Why ? I am just adding the blocked user id to a field .Whats wrong with that?Please explain.

Comment: how do you then check if an id is in this field? how do you remove just one in the middle ?

Comment: @jason: Do you ever intend to do anything with those IDs later?  Cause if so, having a table with one ID per row makes it much less painful; you can use and manipulate the data from within MySQL without mind-numbing amounts of string twiddling.  Plus, it lets you enforce constraints (like "no duplicates"), and works better with triggers and foreign keys and such.

Comment: @cHao I have a table with users with where sno of each user is a new row but blocked_users for that user will be users_id in a single field right.I am going to check if the user is blocked already or should I add the user id again.

Comment: No. You need to create an intersection table. `users_blocked_users` or something. `user_id` would be the blocker, and `blocked_user_id` would be the blocked user.

Comment: @jason: If you already have a users table, and just want a global list of which of those users are blocked, it gets even easier.  Just add an `is_blocked` column to the users table.  If you have a list of blocked users for each user, then have a separate table with two ID columns: the ID of the blocker, and that of the blockee.

Comment: @cHao can you show what you mean I am confused.Sorry.Thanks for your time.

Comment: `create table blocked_users (blocker_id int references users (id), blockee_id int references users (id));`.  Now, to get a list of users that user A has blocked, `select blockee_id from blocked_users where blocker_id = A`.  To see if a user A has blocked user B, `select count(*) from blocked_users where blockee_id = B and blocker_id = A`.  To find a list of most-blocked users (possible troublemakers), `select blockee_id, count(blocker_id) blockers from blocked_users group by blockee_id order by blockers desc`.  Try doing *that* with a comma-separated list in a reasonable amount of time... :)

Comment: @cHao where can I learn more about using references and block/unblock user in database ? ANy tutorial.By the way thanks for that approach I did not know that existed even.Thanks.

Comment: The MySQL manual has a bunch of info on `references`, keys, and all that fun stuff.  Also, google "1NF" and "sql anti-patterns".

Comment: That last search will actually find you a PDF of a book listing common missteps in database design.  What you're doing here is the very first one.  :)

Comment: Thanks for that reading it now.Will I correct my approach after reading the book?

Comment: Probably.  The book suggests solutions for each anti-pattern it identifies.

Comment: What can I do to learn the right approach ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right off the bat, let me tell you that storing CSV values in a database is almost **never** a good idea! It demonstrates poor database design and bad data integrity. It'll likely cause issues further down the line and make working with the data later much more difficult.

Anyway, that having been said, if you still wish to do this, you can use [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/function.implode) to conver the array into a string, that can then be inserted into your MySQL database:

```
$dbString = implode(',', $ids);
```

It would be much better to store the blocked users in another link table.